# Is begin/end required each time you change libGDX enableBlending?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have some background without transparent pixels and then some sprites with transparent pixels. Following libGDX docs, I'm doing something like this:

```
spriteBatch.begin();  
spriteBatch.disableBlending();  
spriteBatch.draw(background, ...);  
spriteBatch.enableBlending();  
spriteBatch.draw(sprite, ...);  
spriteBatch.end();
```

However, I just read this blog post, that suggest you have to use begin/end each time.

http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=179&show_all=true

```
spriteBatch.disableBlending();  
spriteBatch.begin();  
spriteBatch.draw(backgroundRegion, 0, 0, 320, 480);  
spriteBatch.end();  

spriteBatch.enableBlending();  
spriteBatch.begin();  
spriteBatch.draw(someTextureRegion1, 10, 30);  
spriteBatch.draw(someTextureRegion2, 50, 20);  
spriteBatch.draw(someTextureRegion3, 30, 90);  
spriteBatch.end();
```

Is this really required?

My code seems to work, there are no errors reported, but I don't know how to test if it works better or worse than the second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling/disabling blending, causes the batch to flush, which is practically the same as calling end/begin. It is not required to do this yourself, although you probably should be aware of this happening anyway. So you don't have to call end/begin, but should keep changing blending to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks. Is flushing more expensive than difference between rendering a single 800x480 texture with blending enabled vs not enabled?

Comment: flushing is not related to blending. changing blending (or texture) just implies a flush, causing the batch (up till that point) to be rendered. Therefor flush is considered to be an expensive operation, but rendering a single texture is relatively (only four vertices) more expensive.